# wix installer schema not found

Tags: xml, wix

I am new with Wix installer.
I am having problem with building the set-up project.

It says;

> The Bundle element contains an unexpected child element
>   'util:RegistrySearch'

I have already referenced the dll into the project and have;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" 
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
```

in the `bundle.wxs`

When I go to the link below;
http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension

I have the error ;

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable

However; when I comment out the .UtilExtension and util:RegistrySearch, the project builds and works well. I think it should not build if it is a schema problem because;

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
```

stays still there.

Comment: Re: "When I go to the link..." An XML namespace uses a URI (_identifier_) not a URL (_locater_). There is no problem if the URI can't be used as a URL, though some schema publishers do us the favor of providing a copy of the namespace's schema as an XSD document or a specification or other documentation at a URL that matches the URI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please add the reference to the "WixUtilExtension.dll" in your wixproject. That will fix your problem!

Comment: it is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin

Comment: I have already referenced the dll into the project. Its magically solved.Just reopened visual studio. I dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that works well for anyone who is working with a *Wix Project*, correct? In my case, I am running the **`candle.exe`** and **`light.exe`** in two existing WXS files via the command line. The URI scheme `xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"` present in my WXS file is still not found. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using candle and light directly, add "-ext WixBalExtension" to each invocation to pull in the needed.

```
candle.exe -nologo -out foo.wixobj -ext WixBalExtension -arch x64 foo.wxs
light.exe -nologo -out foo-1.0.0.msi -ext WixBalExtension foo.wixobj
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution mentioned by Hack Saw is documented here, by the way:

https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/

> When building the bundle, the WixBalExtension must be provided. If the
>   above code was in a file called "example.wxs", the following steps
>   would create an "example.exe" bundle:
>
> ```
> candle.exe example.wxs -ext WixBalExtension light.exe example.wixobj
> -ext WixBalExtension
> ```