# Error CNDL0200: WixBalExtension Schema

Tags: xml, wix, xsd

My wxs file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Bundle Name="Sample" UpgradeCode="C8C5D724-FCDC-49b5-8556-4A95EC6F5B12" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="XXX">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="" SupressOptionsUI="yes" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage Id="msifcbovj12_lvw" Name="MSIFile" SourceFile="D:\MSIFile.msi" />
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

When I run **candle.exe** I take the following error:

*Error CNDL0200 : The BootstrapperApplicationRef element contains an unhandled extension element 'bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication'. Please ensure that the extension for elements in the 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension' namespace has been provided.*

The URI http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension returns: *"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."*

I've tried the alternative cited in http://sourceforge.net/p/wix/feature-requests/742/ but not resolved.

Have added the appropriate references of the libraries in my WixProject as [wix installer schema not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698895/wix-installer-schema-not-found/23767205#23767205), but not solved.

I'm almost giving up. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 8):

I ended up here due to a search for the same error message, but in my case I was using a WiX project in Visual Studio. Though it's a bit late, I thought I'd provide the solution to my variation of the problem in case someone ends up here (like I did) in the future.

It turned out that what I needed to do was go to Solution Explorer, right-click on the WiX project's References and click "Add Reference...". Then in the "Browse" tab of the "Add Reference" window, make sure you are in the "bin" subfolder of the folder where WiX was installed ("C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10" in my case), select the appropriate "Wix____Extension.dll" (for me it was "WixUtilExtension.dll"), click the "Add" button, then click "OK".

In case you aren't sure which "Wix_____Extension.dll" is appropriate, find the extension element you are trying to use in the [WiX Toolset Manual Table of Contents](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/) (*n.b.* link is for WiX Version 3.x). Doing so should help you figure it out.

Comment: In my case, I had to add the WixBalExtension.dll

Answer (score 5):

Try the below arguments when running candle.exe and light.exe, this should solve your issue:

```
candle.exe -ext WixBalExtension yourwxsfilename.wxs
light.exe -ext WixBalExtension yourwxsfilename.wixobj
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding reference to C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixBalExtension.dll solved the issue for me.