# Setup Wix v4 Installer for Console Application

Tags: asp.net, wix4

I want to create a Installer for a Asp.Net Core WebAPI as a Windows Service.

But during setup I always get errors from wix.

I started setting up a Console Application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal">
    <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper1" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="FSeidl" UpgradeCode="5366e410-23a7-4027-857a-e3de98c8081c">

        <BootstrapperApplication>
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
                    LicenseUrl=""
                    Theme="hyperlinkLicense" />
        </BootstrapperApplication>
        
        <Chain>
            <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
            <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
            <PackageGroupRef Id="BundlePackages"/>
            <ExePackage
                    DetectCondition="DetectedSomethingVariable"
                    UninstallArguments="-uninstall"
                    SourceFile="../ConsoleTest/bin/Debug/net7.0/ConsoleTest.exe" />
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>

    <Fragment>
        <PackageGroup Id="BundlePackages">
            <PackageGroupRef Id="PrereqPackages"/>
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <PackageGroup Id="PrereqPackages">
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

But I always get the error:

```
D:\Tests\WixTest\Bootstrapper1\Bundle.wxs(7) : error WIX0200: The BootstrapperApplication element contains an un
handled extension element 'WixStandardBootstrapperApplication'. Please ensure that the extension for elements in
 the 'http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal' namespace has been provided.
```

I got the components from https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/burn/wixstdba/.

Is there anything I missed?

I checked the following entry:
[Error CNDL0200: WixBalExtension Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807309/error-cndl0200-wixbalextension-schema)

but it is using a older version of wix.

wix build -ext WixBalExtension .\Bundle.wxs

returned:

```
wix.exe : error WIX0144: The extension 'WixBalExtension' could not be found. Checked paths: WixBalExtension
```

Maybe the name of the extension has changed in v4, but I couldn't found a list of extensions available.

https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/wixdev/extensions/extensions/ is for v3 and is no longer maintained.
In the new https://wixtoolset.org/docs/intro/ there is no list of supported extensions either.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `WixToolset.Bal.wixext` NuGet package to your .wixproj.

Comment: Ok, no I can create it using the the ide